# Create subset of data using conditions from another data frame

Tags: r

I would like to use something like `dplyr` to create a subset of data from one data frame using conditions from another data frame. So in one data frame I have a set of data with minimum and maximum years and other sea-level data `lsp` , and in another frame I have a time series of ocean dynamics. For each row in the `lsp` dataframe, I would like to extract every year between the minimum and maximum ages in the `dynamics` data frame and create a sub set of data. I think this will require a for loop. Does anyone have any idea if this is possible?

Desired output using row 1 of LSP as an example:

### Row 1 LSP (simplified) is:

| Age min | Age max |
| --- | --- |
| 1997 | 2007 |

I want to use this information to create a data frame like this from the dynamics file:

### Subset

| Year | Dynamics |
| --- | --- |
| 1997 | 125 |
| 1998 | 109 |
| 1999 | 152 |
| 2000 | 161 |
| 2001 | 106 |
| 2002 | 120 |
| 2003 | 58 |
| 2004 | 68 |
| 2005 | 110 |
| 2006 | 144 |
| 2007 | 100 |

Many thanks

```
## LSP data
structure(list(Depth = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 
8.5, 10.5, 13.5, 14.5, 18.5, 19.5, 27.5, 28.5, 32, 35.5, 40.5, 
41.5), RSL = c(0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, -0.04, -0.01, -0.03, 0, 
0.04, 0.03, 0, -0.01, -0.05, -0.07, -0.19, -0.24, -0.31, -0.31, 
-0.27, -0.29), RSL_err_1sig = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1), Age_mean = c(2001.754499, 1994.278776, 1987.678949, 1980.805889, 
1973.270485, 1965.018421, 1957.442729, 1952.134369, 1949.031929, 
1945.148184, 1939.132213, 1936.957531, 1927.311071, 1924.379033, 
1897.26123, 1892.977317, 1876.1995, 1858.135589, 1825.967544, 
1820.605298), Age.min = c(1996.752238, 1985.111654, 1977.483594, 
1968.26211, 1961.886124, 1958.219318, 1947.496532, 1943.084044, 
1941.761439, 1935.843414, 1923.952516, 1920.057048, 1906.228232, 
1902.242998, 1875.327613, 1869.925103, 1834.992176, 1811.928966, 
1784.998245, 1767.524866), Age.max = c(2006.75676, 2003.445898, 
1997.874304, 1993.349668, 1984.654846, 1971.817524, 1967.388926, 
1961.184694, 1956.302419, 1954.452954, 1954.31191, 1953.858014, 
1948.39391, 1946.515068, 1919.194847, 1916.029531, 1917.406824, 
1904.342212, 1866.936843, 1873.68573)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

## Dynamics (only head)

structure(list(Year = 1815:1820, dynamics = c(-76.01893261, -64.50519732, 
-66.06270761, -76.22822397, -72.35960029, -77.34157443)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: somehow I don't quite follow your question, can you show the expected output based on your input data here?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, sorry about that - so for row 1 in LSP which has a minimum age of 1997 and a maximum age of 2007 I want to extract all of the data between 1997 and 2007 in the dynamics data frame and create a subset. I want to do that for every row in the LSP data frame so row two is 1985 and 2003 so then I want a second subset of data with everything from 1985–2003 in it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Got the idea of what you want to do but have some doubts: 1. How would your output look like? Can you add the desired output to the question? It is a bit tough visualizing from the question itself. 2. You want to consider every year between the minimum and maximum ages, how do you want to take that? Suppose the minimum age is 1996.752, so should you consider 1996 or 1997?

Comment: Hi both, I have added an example table of what I need, hopefully this makes things clearer? I think rounding up will be fine so 1996.752 will be 1997.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option with `Map` and `subset` -

```
Map(function(x, y) subset(dynamics, Year >= x & Year <= y), 
                   LSP$Age.min, LSP$Age.max)
```

The same logic can be implemented using `tidyverse` functions as well.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map2(LSP$Age.min, LSP$Age.max, ~dynamics %>% filter(Year >= .x & Year <= .y))
```

Comment: Ah great, thank you - the ```tidyverse``` code is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 2):

As long as your dataset isn't huge, I would take something like the following approach.

1. Add the (nested) dynamics dataset to each row of your lsp dataset
2. Unnest the dynamics dataset to get one row per year
3. Filter out years that aren't relevant

(Optional)

4. Renest the dynamics columns to you have one row per lsp record with a tibble for all relevant years from the dynamics set.

```
lsp %>%
    add_column(dynamics %>% nest(data = everything())) %>%
    unnest(data) %>%
    filter(year >= min & year <= max) %>%
    nest(filtered = c(year, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this does what you want to do. First assign names to your input data, so later you know what my codes mean.

```
lsp <- structure(list(Depth = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 
8.5, 10.5, 13.5, 14.5, 18.5, 19.5, 27.5, 28.5, 32, 35.5, 40.5, 
41.5), RSL = c(0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, -0.04, -0.01, -0.03, 0, 
0.04, 0.03, 0, -0.01, -0.05, -0.07, -0.19, -0.24, -0.31, -0.31, 
-0.27, -0.29), RSL_err_1sig = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1), Age_mean = c(2001.754499, 1994.278776, 1987.678949, 1980.805889, 
1973.270485, 1965.018421, 1957.442729, 1952.134369, 1949.031929, 
1945.148184, 1939.132213, 1936.957531, 1927.311071, 1924.379033, 
1897.26123, 1892.977317, 1876.1995, 1858.135589, 1825.967544, 
1820.605298), Age.min = c(1996.752238, 1985.111654, 1977.483594, 
1968.26211, 1961.886124, 1958.219318, 1947.496532, 1943.084044, 
1941.761439, 1935.843414, 1923.952516, 1920.057048, 1906.228232, 
1902.242998, 1875.327613, 1869.925103, 1834.992176, 1811.928966, 
1784.998245, 1767.524866), Age.max = c(2006.75676, 2003.445898, 
1997.874304, 1993.349668, 1984.654846, 1971.817524, 1967.388926, 
1961.184694, 1956.302419, 1954.452954, 1954.31191, 1953.858014, 
1948.39391, 1946.515068, 1919.194847, 1916.029531, 1917.406824, 
1904.342212, 1866.936843, 1873.68573)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

dynamics <- structure(list(Year = 1815:1820, dynamics = c(-76.01893261, -64.50519732, 
-66.06270761, -76.22822397, -72.35960029, -77.34157443)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then the actual codes to get the subset.

```
# first get info of years from the "lsp" dataset
# following your example in your comments
year_min  <- list()
year_max  <- list()
all_years <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(lsp)){
  year_min[[i]] <- round(lsp$Age.min[[i]])
  year_max[[i]] <- round(lsp$Age.max[[i]])
  all_years[[i]] <- c(year_min[[i]]:year_max[[i]])
  all_years[[i]] <- as.data.frame(all_years[[i]])
  colnames(all_years[[i]]) <- "Year"
}

# now join the info on "Year" from "lsp" data with "dynamics" data to get the subset
library(dplyr)

subset_output <- list()

for (i in 1:length(all_years)){
  subset_output[[i]] <- left_join(dynamics,all_years[[i]])
}
```